# TypeScript can't assign an Object Type to Record<string, unknown>

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm learning TypeScript, and decided to try implement it in a small portion of my codebase to get the ball rolling. Specifically, what I'm refactoring now is related to a fixture "factory" for the purpose of generating fixtures for Jest tests.

In addition to these factories, which spit out certain Objects, I also have some helper methods that make things like generating multiple objects a bit easier.

A factory is fairly simple, it looks something like this (the values are spoofed with faker.js):

```js
function channelFactory(): ChannelItem {
  return { foo: "bar" }
}
```

A ChannelItem is just a simple Object containing some keys

```js
interface ChannelItem { foo: string; }
```

And as an example of one of those helper methods, I have a `createMany` function that takes in a Factory function and a Count as arguments

```js
function createMany(factory: () => Record<string, unknown>, count = 1): Record<string, any>[] {
  // A for loop that calls the factory, pushes those into an array and returns that array
}
```

However, if I try to use these factories somewhere, for example in this function that persists some created channels into the DB, I get the TS compiler warning me about `Record<string, any>[]` not being assignable to `ChannelItem[]`.

```js
function saveChannels(payload: ChannelItem[]): void { // Unimportant implementation details }
```

```js
const items = createMany(channelFactory, 5);
saveChannels(items) // => Argument type Record<string, any>[] is not assignable to parameter type ChannelItem[]   Type Record<string, any> is not assignable to type ChannelItem
```

I know this is a commonly known issue with Interfaces specifically (Issue [#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)) and that the potential solution would be to declare a `type` rather than an `interface`, however in this situation I still get the same warning.

```js
type ChannelItem = { foo: string } // Still gives me the above warning
```

What would the ideal way of making my `factory` functions more generic here be?

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with #15300; see [this snippet](https://tsplay.dev/NdrYkW); you can assign objects (of non-interface types) to records because TS will give the object an implicit index signature.  But your problem is that you're trying to assign a record to an object; there's no such thing as an "implicit set of specific properties" and TS has no idea is `Record<string, any>` will have a `foo` property or not.  The answers here are the correct response to "what would the ideal way of making my factory functions more generic", but this comment addresses "what am I missing".

Comment: Since those are technically two questions (why is my approach not working? what is the right approach?) they have two separate answers.  Which is your *primary* question?  We should [pick one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) and then either downplay/remove the other, or move it to its own post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the createMany function generic:

```js
function createMany<K extends string, T>(factory: () => Record<K, T>, count = 1): Record<K, T>[] {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    arr.push(factory());
  }
  return arr;
}

const items = createMany(channelFactory, 5);

console.log(items);
// Prints:
//[
//  { foo: 'bar' },
//  { foo: 'bar' },
//  { foo: 'bar' },
//  { foo: 'bar' },
//  { foo: 'bar' }
//]
```

I made `K extends string` because you specified you want your record to have string keys. T can be anything you want.

Just have to fill in the functions yourself, not sure what you want done in those.

Answer (score 1):

The `createMany` doesn't even need to know the type `factory` returns.

You can make it generic for more flexibility.

```
interface ChannelItem { foo: string; }
function channelFactory(): ChannelItem {
  return { foo: "bar" }
}

function createMany<T>(factory: () => T, count = 1): T[] {
  // A for loop that calls the factory, pushes those into an array and returns that array
  return []
}

function saveChannels(payload: ChannelItem[]): void {  }

const items = createMany(channelFactory, 5);
saveChannels(items)
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs4hBANgSUgFtkBvZGAe0oC5kBnMKUAcwG5kBfAKBgFcQCMMEohkCTNjwAxRGEpQAngAoAlHQxYcBYmW7JkUCGD5Qx5KrWQAiAEZwo1rtx68BQkWIRG4kALJYigA8ACoAfMrwQgqKdGrIALxhyCEANOKUAmCJyACM6ikA2gC6egYA9OXIAIIUCsi41AAOyGCY2QhwuLj0regoUfJK6U189P29bZT0KKDyyFgLUFBwigsgACaGxqYgk%201LK4r62yZmyCUu3G6CwqIMcABuEJpSPcpNq41wGxqS2oQIEQSgVHpRgFtyM5uAhRIxkMBiL0EuIfP5AsoJFoZHIYukAKyqNjcehPF7-PD0ZSIoH0VRAA)